# Using date-time index slows down groupby apply in Pandas?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following structure (about 100 million rows):

```
Date     Value  ID
'1/1/17' 500    1
'1/2/17' 550    1
'1/4/17' 600    2
```

If I do:

```
def get_coeff_var(group):
    group['coeff_var'] = group['Value'].std()/group['Value'].mean()
    return group

df = df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: get_coeff_var(x))
```

It completes extremely quickly.

But if I first set the index to the date and get the last month of data, then the same apply function takes an enormous (i.e. I can't even wait for it to complete) amount of time:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df = df.last('1M')
df = df.groupby(['ID']).apply(lambda x: get_coeff_var(x))
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost always, mutating inside a groupby-apply is a bad idea - in general it takes a slow path, although I'm not sure what the exact issue is here.

In your case, the idiomatic, and much faster way to do this transformation is as follows, and should be fast regardless of your index.

```
gb = df.groupby('ID')['Value']
df['coeff_var'] = gb.transform('std') / gb.transform('mean')
```